# Data transmission between Android and C# over Internet

Tags: c#, android, tcp

I'm trying to make a simple program for my object-oriented programming project. My team and I decided to create a program for restaurants and customers. Customers have an android app that helps them make orders or ask for the waiters etc. and restaurant have a desktop app(written in C#) which gets notifications from customers that have made orders etc..

The problem is that we haven't learnt anything about data transmissions yet and I don't know even where to start.

I'm just asking for a good resource about data transmission for a complete begginer. I'm making a class diagram right now, so I have to know at least which classes I should make in order to implement it.

In addition, I'll use database for login information of customers. Can I make an alternative solution to my problem by using database for orders, notifications etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your question the closest thing that comes in my mind in json parsing.
You can easily parse your android Data in JSON. and then push it to the server using PHP after that in C# getting data from server and fetching JSON data is easy. Give it a shot.

Comment: That looks interesting, thanks for the reply. I'll look into that.

Comment: I used the same procedure in my C# windows 8.1 app and worked for me. But on quick comment prepare a database on server side that keeps the track of all the JSON that you push through android.